# Как определить что пользователь отправил число боту а не строку?

Tags: python, discord.py

Я хочу сделать проверку на то что пользователь отправил команду с цифрами а не строки

```
@bot.command()
async def greetingsCHANL(ctx,amount: int = None ):
    if amount == None:
        await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.name} Введи iD канала преведствия")
    else:
        if type(amount) == str: #isinstance
            await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.name} Введи iD канала преведствия")
        else:
            cursorLB.execute('UPDATE allvariables SET greetingsCHANL =?', [f"{amount}"])
            # cursor.execute("UPDATES users SET date +=? WHERE id = ?",(massage,member.id))
            Allvariables.commit()
            await ctx.send(cursorLB.execute("SELECT greetingsCHANL FROM allvariables ".format()).fetchone()[0])
```

Comment: Аннотация `amount: int` не имеет смысла, потому что `amount` всегда будет строкой. Учитывая, что вы прописали None по умолчанию, правильная аннотация будет `amount: Optional[str] = None`

Comment: Чтобы проверить, состоит ли строка только из чисел, можно использовать метод `amount.isdigit()`

Comment: Спасибо! буду скоро проверять

Comment: Если число может быть со знаком минус (то есть не только из цифр), то можно просто попробовать распарсить его с помощью `int(amount)` (для целых) или `float(amount)` (для вещественных), перехватив возможную ошибку ValueError с помощью try-except

Comment: @andreymal
у меня на ошибка Unresolved reference 'Optional'

Comment: Ну да, надо его импортировать из модуля typing

Comment: @andreymal Спасибо большое! Все получилось)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот решение проблемы:

```
@bot.command()
    async def greetingsCHANL(ctx,amount: Optional[str] = None ):
        if amount == None:
            await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.name} Введи iD канала преведствия")
        else:
            if amount.isdigit() == False: #isinstance
                await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.name} Введи iD канала преведствия")
            else:
                cursorLB.execute('UPDATE allvariables SET greetingsCHANL =?', [f"{amount}"])
                # cursor.execute("UPDATES users SET date +=? WHERE id = ?",(massage,member.id))
                Allvariables.commit()
                await ctx.send(cursorLB.execute("SELECT greetingsCHANL FROM allvariables ".format()).fetchone()[0])
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Зачем вы повторили код из вопроса?

Comment: @0xdb этот код отличается от кода из вопроса (что, впрочем, не отменяет того, что ответ непонятен)

Comment: @andreymal возможно, я же не буду из очереди проверок оба в diff посылать.

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать что-то вроде:

```
 number = int(input("Введите число: "))
```

И прописать исключения try, exept, для обработки, если пользователь введëт не число.